Angular unit test of conditionally rendered information
I'm brand new to using unit testing in Angular and I ran into something I could have sworn was common with a simple solution. I've got a component that's conditionally rendered.
<div *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
  etc...
</div>

In the basic spec.ts supplied with the component I tossed in the following:
it('should be visible when visible is true and invisible when false', ()=> {
  component.visible = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeTruthy();
  component.visible = false;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeFalsy();
});

This generates a failure. Depending on if the default value for visible is true or false, the querySelector calls either both return null or both return the component.
I have found a solution to this, but I hate it:
it('should be visible when visible is true and invisible when false', ()=> {
    component.visible = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeTruthy();
    component.visible = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeFalsy();
    }, 1000);
  });

I shouldn't have to insert a delay to get the test to pass. I've seen similar questions asked before, but no answer seems to be available. So what should be done?

Could you try two approaches.

fakeAsync and flush

code:
it('should be visible when visible is true and invisible when false', fakeAsync(()=> {
    component.visible = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeTruthy();
    component.visible = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeFalsy();

  }));


await fixture.whenStable();

code:
it('should be visible when visible is true and invisible when false', async ()=> {
    component.visible = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeTruthy();
    component.visible = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.dialog')).toBeFalsy();

  });


Thanks for the input. I tried both solutions and both failed in the same way as my code without using the timeout. Without the delay, changing the visible doesn't happen.

I'm going to classify this as a classic "doctor, it hurts when I do this" problem. Perhaps I was trying to be too clever testing both enabled and disabled inside an it. When I broke it out to two it functions, the tests behaved properly.
